# In how many parties would the same friends be found?

Tags: combinatorics

A person tries to form as many different parties as he can, out of his 20 friends. Each party should consists of the same number of friends.how many friends should be invited at a time? In how many of these parties would the same friends be found?

I got hang of the first part,the person is trying to form maximum number of parties out of his $20$ friends which is possible when he invites $10$ friends at a time(each party should have same number of friends):
$$20\choose10$$ Therefore $10$ friends should be invited at a time.

But how do I go about solving the next part??

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the second question. Is it asking how many parties contain a given friend? If so, the answer is half of them. But only one party can ever have the same exact set of ten friends, according to the apparent conditions.

Comment: The answer is "none" because if in two parties the same friends were found, then those two parties would have the same members and therefore be the same party.

Answer (score 0):

By the condition specified, each party is distinct, so no party can have **all** participants the same.

If you are asking how many of such parties will have some **particular** person, the answer is $\dbinom11\dbinom{19}{9} = \dbinom{19}{9}$